# Конвертация latex->html

Tags: html, парсер, latex

Добрый день, стоит задача конвертации книг в формате latex в html. Сейчас используются сторонние конверторы, но дальше проводится ручное преобразование документа к нужному виду, что занимает очень много времени. Нужно все это автоматизировать, и наиболее оптимальным вариантом представляется написание своего конвертора, т.е. парсинг latex-документа и преобразование его сразу к нужному виду. 
Вопрос: с какой стороны лучше подойти к этому делу? Парсинг с помощью регулярных выражений по понятным причинам отпал довольно быстро. После поиска в гугле пришел к выводу, что следует написать транслятор latex-кода, подходящий ли это метод?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует достаточно много [средств для перевода](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=LaTeX2HTML) документов на LaTeX в HTML. И возможно стоит все-таки все их перепробовать, прежде чем начинать писать свой инструмент. Если же без этого не обойтись, то разумно взять готовый инструмент с открытым исходным кодом и адаптировать его под себя, например, [LaTeX2HTML](http://www.latex2html.org/) - скрипт на Perl.

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно посмотрю на этот инструмент, но все же, хотелось бы узнать, подходящее ли в данном случае решение - написание своего транслятора? Или, может быть, следует разбираться в совершенно другом направлении?

Comment: Писать свой -- не вижу смысла. Там много. Если написать для шибко ограниченного latex -- то это ненадолго. Потом опять надо дописывать. Из прожектов ещё -- hevea.inria.fr (сам не пробовал, но сайты, правда не на русском, попадались часто)

Comment: Всем спасибо, кажется, нашел то, что мне нужно - PlasTeX, судя по документации, позволяет преобразовать latex-документ в дерево, с которым можно работать.